# How to toggle forms using HTML <select> controls

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am currently developing a web application that requires me to register users according to their category. I have a combo-box in which the user can choose which type of user they are.

I want to do is show a relevant form according to the user's selected value. I'm am using PHP for all the functionality, but I'm a newbie to jQuery. Can anyone show how to implement this or else demonstrate a different way of doing this *without* reloading the page?

Answer (score 4):

You can try using a category dropdown list as shown.

### HTML Code

#### Dropdown

```
<select id="category">
   <option value="#form1">Category 1</option>
   <option value="#form2">Category 2</option>
   <option value="#form3">Category 3</option>
</select>
```

#### Forms

```
<form id="form1">
</form>    

<form id="form2">
</form>

<form id="form3">
</form>
```

### jQuery Code

```
$(function(){
    var forms = $('form'); //cache all Forms
    forms.hide(); //hide initial

    $('#category').on('change', function(){
        forms.hide();                 //on change hide all forms
        var formId = $(this).val();   //get form id to show
        $(formId).show();    //find form by its id in cached forms and show.
    });

});
```

Comment: yograj-gupta I tried to use your code but the on('change') doesnt work or the only thing you code does it hides the forms and shows me the select option.when chosing one option to toggle between the two forms i get no response.but please note i have no #form1,#form2 defined in my css i dnt know if that might be a problem.

Comment: Which jquery version you are using, please user 1.6 or later to work with `on`.

Comment: can you post your select list, forms tag only and jquery code.

Comment: <p>register as <select name="choice" class="selection" id="categories">                                                             <option value="#form1">Company</option>                                                               <option value="form2">CREDIT PROVIDER</option>                                                                                                                                      </select></p>

Comment: your all option do not have value attribute.

Comment: <form method="post" action="inc/functions.php?action=newagent" id="form1"> <form method="post" action="" id="form2"><p>form2</>

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.8.1.js">
       </script>
          <script type="text/javascript">
           $(function(){
              //alert('jsActive'); 
              var forms = $('form');
              forms.hide();
              $('#categories').one('change',function(){
                  var formid = $(this).val();
             forms.find(formid).show();  
              });
            });
        </script>

Comment: You have missed it is `.on` not `.one`. `.one` executes one time only.

Comment: my bad for using one.thats was a typing error but the way I understand your code its supposed to show a different form everytime i change the seleted value but instead it shows the select and them options but the events are not fired.its there an alternative or please let me know where am i going wrong so i can fix it.thanks

Comment: @Ramz check this demo  http://jsfiddle.net/ug73C/2/ and replace `forms.find(formId).show();` to `$(formId).show();`

Comment: @Ramz and Let me know if issue is persist or not

Comment: Ok yograj its now its firing the events but only when the form loads it shows me category to choose from when choosing second category it doesnt fire any events while my goal it to show a different form,then when going back to the first option it shows the form but it shows both while its supposed to hide the other. thanks man I think I'm getting somewhere now.

Comment: @Ramz, Sorry for late reply, Check whether your are hiding all form on change event `forms.hide();`. I hope, you have solved your issue...

Comment: yep i did solve the issue my man and thanks for all the input its working just fine now and yes i wasn't hiding the forms.and its actually quite easy.But what was missing with your code Yograj was that i have to declare a variable for each form so i can be able to use it when ever i need it at a later stage.thanks againg though

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery [show()](http://api.jquery.com/show) and [hide()](http://api.jquery.com/hide) functions:

Example:

```
$('#form1').hide();
$('#form2').hide();
$('#form3').show();
```

In this example you have forms defined as follows:

```
<form id="form1">...</form>
<form id="form2">...</form>
<form id="form3">...</form>
```

You can also get fancy with it and use [fadeIn()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/) and [fadeOut()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/) if you want some effects.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery `toggle()` function:

```
$('#your_form').toggle();
```

From the [docs:](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

> The matched elements will be revealed or hidden immediately, with no
>   animation, by changing the CSS display property. If the element is
>   initially displayed, it will be hidden; if hidden, it will be shown.
>   The display property is saved and restored as needed. If an element
>   has a display value of inline, then is hidden and shown, it will once
>   again be displayed inline.